# Solaris 11.4 problems under VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, solaris

A while back I downloaded the Oracle VM image for Solaris 11.4 which I loaded into VirtualBox 5.2.34 running on FreeBSD 12.1. So far this hasn't been a pleasant experience.

Today I was running the image for a few hours, doing some minor tests on an opensource project. This evening, I went to halt the image. The VBox disk indicator was hard on, and I couldn't get to the password screen. ssh from the FreeBSD box also just hung. So I reset the image. Now when I try to boot it's stuck in a loop

Grub screen <-> error: couldn't find a valid DVA.

Is there an easy fix for this or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the 11.4 text iso image. Booted, spent a while before figuring out that I needed to run

```
zpool import -fF rpool
```

(everything else I tried failed with "in use" errors etc). Ran `zpool scrub` and then `zpool export`. Rebooted and the VM seems to be back in action.